# Свойство DialogResult у кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема кажется детской, но я почему-то(тупой) не могу до конца разобраться. Необходимо на форме поставить у кнопок свойства DialogResult как "OK" и "Cancel". Допустим у меня есть какая-то проверка на кнопке и код не выполнится, если проверка не пройдет, но форма все-равно закроется(чего мне не надо). Еще я хочу поставить подтверждение на выходе(FormClosing) и дело в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "OK" это сообщение тоже вылетает(в любом случае форма закрывается).И правильно ли я понимаю, что при нажатии на крестик формы срабатывает то же событие, что и по кнопке с DialogResult "Cancel".

Comment: Не устанавливайте кнопкам `DialogResult`. В обработчике клика по кнопке делайте необходимые проверки и устанавливайте `DialogResult` форме кодом

Comment: @АндрейNOP Такое не работает. Если ставлю в обработчике клика, то по первому нажатию устанавливается, но не срабатывает. И необходимо еще раз нажимать

Comment: Вы устанавливаете `DialogResult` кнопке, я же говорю вам установить его форме: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @АндрейNOP Так и сделал. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не задавайте свойство `DialogResult` кнопке — при клике по этой кнопке, значение `DialogResult` автоматически копируется в одноименное свойство формы *безусловно*.

Просто подпишитесь на событие клика по кнопке и устанавливайте `DialogResult` форме только если вам это действительно необходимо:

```
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (...)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Ссылка по теме: [MSDN, Свойство `Form.DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx), почитайте раздел "Комментарии"

Answer (score 0):

Вам вторым параметром при `FormClosing` приходит `FormClosingEventArgs` который является наследником `CancelEventArgs`, укажите `Cancel` как `true`, при нажатии например, отмены, а при ОК, ничего не делайте. Форма будет закрыта только в случае когда вы укажите для `Cancel` `false`, или вовсе ничего не будете делать с данным полем. По умолчанию равно `false`.

Comment: Если вы про e.Cancel = false, то форма все равно закрывается

Comment: @Ari100krat: "Форма будет закрыта только в случае когда вы укажите для `Cancel` `false`"

Comment: Да про это я знаю. Я хочу чтобы FormClosing не срабатывал при нажатии на OK. Потому, что это будет работать
, как если я нажал одновременно и CANCEL и OK